# How to fire a resize on the window width in em based on font-size:100%

Tags: jquery, font-size

I have several elements that need adjustment based on the height of the header and doing it with CSS is a pain the ass because the header changes so I need something that will not hide the targeted content when the header is sticky and the header only sticks at the min-width 62em.

If I change the '62em' to '992' it works fine on my 1 pixel device (my desktop) but I need the resize to fire on 62em.

```
var headerheight =  $(".header").height();
var windowwidth =  '62em';

$(window).on('resize load', function() {

if ($(window).width() >= windowwidth) {
    
   $('.bat-content .target').css({"padding-top": headerheight + "px", "margin-top": - headerheight + "px"});
}
});
```

Based on the first answer, which was wrong but helped me tremendously, this appears to do the trick:

```
var headerheight =  $(".header").height();
var windowwidth =  '992';
var ems = windowwidth / parseFloat($("html").css("font-size"))

$(window).on('resize load', function() {

if ($(window).width() >= ems) {

   $('.bat-content .target').css({"padding-top": headerheight + "px", "margin-top": - headerheight + "px"});
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var headerheight =  $(".header").height();
var windowwidth =  '992';
var ems = windowwidth / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"))

$(window).on('resize load', function() {

if ($(window).width() > ems) {

   $('.bat-content .target').css({"padding-top": headerheight + "px", "margin-top": - headerheight + "px"});
}
});
```